# Downloaded Songs/Music Videos Stopped Playing After iOS 10.3.1 Update

Tags: ipad, video, music, ios

After upgrading to iOS 10.3.1, my iPad Air 2 is no longer playing music videos (TV icon), which I downloaded using Syncios. I can see that the music videos are there on my device, but they won’t play.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem mentioned with a few other third-party audio/video apps. The solution offered was to delete the local song, video or audiobook from your iPad, then re-download it. This is a bug caused by iOS 10.3.

Comment: Thanks for response, however the problem is that the song or music video does not show up in the Ipad after you  transfer from Syncios.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case after I looked up what Syncios actually was. Sorry I couldn’t be of help.